# AD Account lockout

Tags: active-directory

Having issues with a active directory account keeps getting locked out.

Have taken the following troubleshooting steps:
1. Cleared all passwords in Credential manager -> Control Panel 
2. Cleared all passwords in Stored User Names and Passwords -> rundll32 keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr
3.Check the client's PC time to ensure a match with the DC

LOGS:

TimeCreated  : 1/24/2018 1:40:59 PM
ProviderName : Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Id           : 4625
Message      : An account failed to log on.

```
           Subject:
            Security ID:            S-1-5-18
            Account Name:           *********
            Account Domain:         *********
            Logon ID:               0x3E7

           Logon Type:                      2

           Account For Which Logon Failed:
            Security ID:            S-1-0-0
            Account Name:           *********
            Account Domain:         EWNZ

           Failure Information:
            Failure Reason:         Account locked out.
            Status:                 0xC0000234
            Sub Status:             0x0

           Process Information:
            Caller Process ID:      0x9c8
            Caller Process Name:    C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe

           Network Information:
            Workstation Name:       *********
            Source Network Address: 127.0.0.1
            Source Port:            0

           Detailed Authentication Information:
            Logon Process:          User32
            Authentication Package: Negotiate
            Transited Services:     -
            Package Name (NTLM only):       -
            Key Length:             0

           This event is generated when a logon request fails. It is generated on the computer where access was
           attempted.

           The Subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most
           commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or Services.exe.

           The Logon Type field indicates the kind of logon that was requested. The most common types are 2
           (interactive) and 3 (network).

           The Process Information fields indicate which account and process on the system requested the logon.

           The Network Information fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is
           not always available and may be left blank in some cases.

           The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.
            - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.
            - Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.
            - Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key was
           requested.
```

TimeCreated  : 1/24/2018 1:40:41 PM
ProviderName : Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Id           : 4625
Message      : An account failed to log on.

```
           Subject:
            Security ID:            S-1-5-18
            Account Name:           *********
            Account Domain:         *********
            Logon ID:               0x3E7

           Logon Type:                      2

           Account For Which Logon Failed:
            Security ID:            S-1-0-0
            Account Name:           *********
            Account Domain:         *********

           Failure Information:
            Failure Reason:         Account locked out.
            Status:                 0xC0000234
            Sub Status:             0x0

           Process Information:
            Caller Process ID:      0x9c8
            Caller Process Name:    C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe

           Network Information:
            Workstation Name:       *********
            Source Network Address: 127.0.0.1
            Source Port:            0

           Detailed Authentication Information:
            Logon Process:          User32
            Authentication Package: Negotiate
            Transited Services:     -
            Package Name (NTLM only):       -
            Key Length:             0

           This event is generated when a logon request fails. It is generated on the computer where access was
           attempted.

           The Subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most
           commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or Services.exe.

           The Logon Type field indicates the kind of logon that was requested. The most common types are 2
           (interactive) and 3 (network).

           The Process Information fields indicate which account and process on the system requested the logon.

           The Network Information fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is
           not always available and may be left blank in some cases.

           The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.
            - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.
            - Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.
            - Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key was
           requested.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a service that is using faulty credentials.  Check services.msc and make sure any services that are running as a domain user have appropriate credentials.

@Clayton also points out it could also be a scheduled task (svchost obfuscates so much!)

Comment: Could also be a scheduled task...

Comment: @Clayton good call!